# R sprintf or paste getting c(value) results

Tags: r

I have two databases that are on different servers.  So I'm querying one database putting that result into a list. Then trying to sprintf or paste that list into another sql query.  When I use sprintf or paste I get the c() around the list values.

```
    testing <- sprintf("all codes in %s",code_list)
    cat(testing,"\n")
    Results: all codes in c("1", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "F", "N", "R", "S", "Y", "Z", "0", "E", "H", "A") 

dput(code_list)
structure(list(CODE_CLASS = c("1", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","F", "N","R", "S", "Y", "Z", "0", "E", "H", "A")), .Names = "CODE_CLASS", row.names = c(NA,17L), class = "data.frame")
```

The results I'm hoping for is: **all codes in ("1", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "F", "N", "R", "S", "Y", "Z", "0", "E", "H", "A")** 
basically get rid of the c.

Comment: It appears that the issue is `code_list` but you show us neither the contents nor the code that generated it. could you please run `dput(code_list)` and paste the results into your question?

Comment: I just added the dput code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `glue` to do this

```
library(glue)
glue("all code in ({toString(unlist(code_list))})")
#all code in (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, F, N, R, S, Y, Z, O, E, H, A)
```

#### Update

If we need it in quotes

```
glue("all code in ({toString(shQuote(unlist(code_list)))})")
#all code in ('1', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'F', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'Y', 'Z', 'O', 'E', 'H', 'A')
```

Or in double quotes

```
glue("all code in ({toString(dQuote(unlist(code_list)))})")
```

#### data

```
code_list <- list(c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), c("F", "N", "R", "S", "Y", "Z", 
    "O", "E", "H", "A"))
```

Comment: Need them in Quotes.

Comment: @Tony In that case, just wrap with `as.character(glue(..`

Comment: That put the whole string in quotes, need each character in quotes, see my question post about what I expect for a results.
     as.character(glue("all code in ({toString(unlist(code_list))})"))
     [1] "all code in (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, F, N, R, S, Y, Z, 0, E, H, A)"

Answer (score 0):

```
testing <- sprintf("all codes in %s",paste0("(",toString(unlist(code_list)),")"))
> cat(testing,"\n")
all codes in (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, F, N, R, S, Y, Z, 0, E, H, A)
```

But you can go ahead and directly do:

```
cat("all codes in",paste0("(",toString(unlist(code_list)),")"),"\n")
all codes in (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, F, N, R, S, Y, Z, 0, E, H, A)
```

Comment: Need them in Quotes.